# Hibernate inheritance with @OneToOne -> too many left outer joins

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate with @OneToOne on a polymorphic base class and unfortunately it generates random left outer joins with other sub tables of `SuperClass` apart from the actual sub class table. I'm only querying `CalledClass`, which itself is connected via bi-directional OneToMany to another class. `SuperClass` has a lot of tables which inherit from it, they only share the `id` field and nothing else. How can I prevent hibernate from generating left outer joins over the Child Tables of `SuperClass` when querying `CalledClass`? Is it possible to deduce the right class type of `SuperClass` when querying `CalledClass` and only joining this class table?

```java
@Entity
public class CalledClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    UUID id;

    @OneToOne
    AdditionalStuff stuff;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    SuperClass<?, ?> content;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "oc_id")
    OtherClass oc;

  

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "BlockType")
public abstract class SuperClass<E, T extends SomeClass> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    long id;

}
```